# Array to string in php replace spaces with new lines

Tags: php

`$reply[$c]` Contains "123 123 123" How can i convert so `$reply[$c]` equals `123\n123\n123`

> echo str_replace(' ',"\n",explode("\n", $reply[$c]));

My code that failed ^

Here is the code showing how `$reply[$c]` was formed and used im pretty new to php.

Quick code reference:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

        //Fetch Results from Mysql (Store in an accociative array, because they wont be in the right order)
        $rows = array();
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $rows[$row['id']] = $row;
        }

        //Call Sphinxes BuildExcerpts function
        if ($CONF['body'] == 'excerpt') {
            $docs = array();
            foreach ($ids as $c => $id) {
                $docs[] = "'".mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($rows[$id]['body']))."'";
            }
            $result = mysql_query("CALL SNIPPETS((".implode(',',$docs)."),'{$CONF['sphinx_index']}','".mysql_real_escape_string($q)."')",$sphinxql);
            $reply = array();
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                $reply[] = $row['snippet'];
            }
        }

        foreach ($ids as $c => $id) {
            $row = $rows[$id];
            print ($reply[$c]); //Need to replace spaces with new lines here
        }
}
```

Full code reference: http://nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example5-sphinxql.phps

Comment: Why are you passing array instead of string? What for this "explode"?

Comment: Should be `$reply[$c] = echo str_replace(' ',"\n", $reply[$c]);`

Comment: I get error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'echo' (T_ECHO)

Comment: Ignore what i tried at the start if you look down the bottom of code block you will see `print ($reply[$c])` this prints out `123 123 123` i need it to print out `123\n123\n123`

Comment: Link to code template im using for full code reference: http://www.nearby.org.uk/sphinx/search-example5-sphinxql.phps

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to `explode` your string. Just replacing the spaces with newlines is enough.

```
echo str_replace(' ', "\n", $reply[$c]);
```